# Ads are looking weird (elements overlapping) according to Admob

Tags: java, android, admob

I am using banner ads and interstitial ads. Everything looks fine on my side. But I got an email that ad elements are overlapping each other. Admob wants me to fix the problem. But I have no idea where the problem is.

I am using  com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:12.0.0 with Android Studio.

For interstitial ads:

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interBannerAdID));
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

if (isNetworkConnected() && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
    mInterstitialAd.show();
}
```

for banner ads:

```
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .build();
    AdSize adsize=AdSize.BANNER;
    adView.setAdSize(adsize);
    adView.setAdUnitId(getActivity().getString(R.string.bannerAdID));
    cv_ad.addView(adView);
    adView.loadAd(request);


adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
        super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
        cv_ad.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        adsVisibility = View.GONE;
    }

@Override
public void onAdLoaded() {
    super.onAdLoaded();
    cv_ad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.swing_up_left);
    cv_ad.startAnimation(animation);
    adsVisibility = View.VISIBLE;
    isAdShown=true;
}
});
```

and layout view for banner ads:

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/ad_card_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dictionary_card_view_height"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#f2f1f1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            >


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here are the screenshot Admob sent to me. But I can not get this view on my test devices. Both emulators and real devices.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Any help would be so appreciated.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: You should probably put your XML..

Comment: thank you leo. just updated.

Answer (score 0):

you should add the AdMob component in your XML like this

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

and add this to your java code in onCreate

```
MobileAds.initialize(this,
        "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

  AdView   mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

ceck out [admob documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner) for more details

Comment: Thank you Mohamed. But I don't think this is the issue here. Documentation also mentions about creating AdView programmatically. Even if you are right how do you explain the problem about interstitial ads?

Comment: I think that the problem is in the size of the ad banner there are default sizes i am not sure if you are using one of them

Comment: I didn't paste the code there but I am setting the adsize. just updated the question. Thank you tough.

Comment: did you try to make the cardview layout_height wrap_content

Comment: I did't try that. It's already 115dp minimum by default. Adsize.BANNER has 50dp,